# Создание триггера

Tags: sql-server, триггер

Имеется 2 таблицы. Продажи и товары. Необходимо создать триггер, который при добавлении новой записи в таблицу с продажами, брал значение столбца Count и убавлял значение Count в таблице товары. Документацию не могу разобрать на msdn, проект требует использования MS SQL, мне же проще и ближе разобраться с mysql, но увы.

Comment: А в чем вопрос? Я, например, могу объяснить, но мне лень делать это за вас, особенно если не было попытки самостоятельного решения.

Comment: Была) Просто стыдно показывать
http://pastebin.ru/i7SSCglL

Comment: Маловато будет - вы просто обновляете количество товара на складе, устанавливая его равным количеству проданного. В чем именно у вас случилась проблема?

Comment: Сообщение 4104, уровень 16, состояние 1, процедура CascadeUpdate, строка 8
Не удалось привязать составной идентификатор "Inserted.Count".

Comment: Ну да, ваш запрос написан криво. Inserted - это "таблица", и обращаться с ней нужно соответственно.